# Pip can't find PyPI package in Artifactory

Tags: python, artifactory, pypi, jfrog-cli

I build the PyPI package and pushed to our on-prem Artifactory by using jfrog CLI and command:

tar.gz

```
./jfrog rt upload --url https://artifacts.XYZ.com/artifactory '--props=pypi.name=xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator;pypi.version=0.0.1.dev20200102111901+dirty.0.g251f725.mock.develop;pypi.normalized.name=xyz-easysdlc-traceability-matrix-generator' --module=xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator --user=**** '--password=****' dist/xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator-0.0.1.dev20200102111901+dirty.0.g251f725.mock.develop.tar.gz pypi-main-dev/xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator/0.0.1.dev20200102111901+dirty.0.g251f725.mock.develop/
```

wheel

```
./jfrog rt upload --url https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory '--props=pypi.name=xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator;pypi.version=0.0.1.dev20200102111901+dirty.0.g251f725.mock.develop;pypi.normalized.name=xyz-easysdlc-traceability-matrix-generator' --module=xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator --user=**** '--password=****' dist/xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator-0.0.1.dev20200102111901+dirty.0.g251f725.mock.develop-py3-none-any.whl pypi-main-dev/xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator/0.0.1.dev20200102111901+dirty.0.g251f725.mock.develop/
```

Both are uploaded successfully.

When I'm installing the pip package from **.whl** file by following steps, it works:

1. Download https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory/webapp/#/artifacts/browse/tree/PyPIInfo/pypi-main-dev-local/xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator/0.0.1.dev20200102111901+dirty.0.g251f725.mock.develop/xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator-0.0.1.dev20200102111901+dirty.0.g251f725.mock.develop-py3-none-any.whl
2. Run `pip install ~/Downloads/xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator-0.0.1.dev20200102111901+dirty.0.g251f725.mock.develop-py3-none-any.whl`

I would then expect, that simply

`pip install --pre --index-url https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-main-dev/simple xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator`

would work, but I'm getting following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator
```

Any guess, guys?

[UPDATE] 
When I run pip install in verbose mode, I'm getting following output:

```
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/kq/3kr8fjgx6fv272mmnglm4lph_wfb11/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-u7ai32js
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/kq/3kr8fjgx6fv272mmnglm4lph_wfb11/T/pip-req-tracker-rxb7443i
Created requirements tracker '/private/var/folders/kq/3kr8fjgx6fv272mmnglm4lph_wfb11/T/pip-req-tracker-rxb7443i'
Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/kq/3kr8fjgx6fv272mmnglm4lph_wfb11/T/pip-install-kegd0en3
Looking in indexes: https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-main-dev/simple
1 location(s) to search for versions of xyz-easysdlc.traceability-matrix-generator:
* https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-main-dev/simple/xyz-easysdlc-traceability-matrix-generator/
Getting page https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-main-dev/simple/xyz-easysdlc-traceability-matrix-generator/
Found index url https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-main-dev/simple
Looking up "https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-main-dev/simple/xyz-easysdlc-traceability-matrix-generator/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): artifacts.xyz.com:443
https://artifacts.xyz.com:443 "GET /artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-main-dev/simple/xyz-easysdlc-traceability-matrix-generator/ HTTP/1.1" 404 None
Status code 404 not in (200, 203, 300, 301)
Could not fetch URL https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-main-dev/simple/xyz-easysdlc-traceability-matrix-generator/: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-main-dev/simple/xyz-easysdlc-traceability-matrix-generator/ - skipping
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'xyz-easysdlc.traceability-matrix-generator': discarding no candidates
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator (from versions: none)
Cleaning up...
Removed build tracker '/private/var/folders/kq/3kr8fjgx6fv272mmnglm4lph_wfb11/T/pip-req-tracker-rxb7443i'
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 382, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 201, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 365, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 311, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    req.populate_link(self.finder, upgrade_allowed, self.require_hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 225, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 906, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator
```

But when I navigate to https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-main-dev/simple/xyz-easysdlc-traceability-matrix-generator/ I can see both, *.whl and *.tar.gz files. Just to make sure, it's not an issue with some "invalid" package name, here are the names of files.

```
xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator-0.0.1.dev20200102111901+dirty.0.g251f725.mock.develop-py3-none-any.whl
xyz_easysdlc.traceability_matrix_generator-0.0.1.dev20200102111901+dirty.0.g251f725.mock.develop.tar.gz
```

Comment: What's the output when you add verbose output, e.g. `pip install -vvv ...`?

Comment: Also, when you visit `https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-main-dev/simple`, does it list your package?

Comment: Thanks @DustinIngram for your hints. I provided this information in the question itself.

Comment: Does your repo require authentication? If you run `curl https://artifacts.xyz.com/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-main-dev/simple/xyz-easysdlc-traceability-matrix-generator/` what do you get?

Comment: @DustinIngram thanks a lot, actually you found the root cause of the issue. When I used authentication, I was able to use pip install. I will just find the misconfiguration of our Artifactory on-prem instance. Anyway the issue is now resolved. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the root cause of this issue. Artifactory is sending HTTP Code 404 even in case you are not authorized (v. 6.10.7). When I authenticated for `pip install`, installation was successful.

Comment: where did you pass credentials? in conf file? or in url directly